# Nested WL.api call breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, onedrive

**Problem**
The problem I'am having is that when i try to call a second `WL.api` from my parent, because i'am in need of the `data` output from the first api, the `script` seem to break. I don't get any error response from the second api. If someone could point me in the right direction with this problem I would be grateful.

**Note**: The first call to fetch the folders work and i get the wanted data. It's when i try to make the second call to fetch the files in the wanted folder that breaks.

My `function` is is called from a button's `onClick` event, this is my `function`:

```
function getFolders() {
       WL.api({
             path: "me/skydrive/files",
             method: "GET"
       }).then(
             function(response) {
               var folders = response.data;
               $.each(folders, function () {
                      var folder = this;
                      if (folder.name == 'FooBar') {
                         WL.api({
                            path: "/" + folder.id + "/files",
                            method: "GET"
                            }).then(
                                function(response2) {
                                    var files = response2.data;
                                    $.each(files, function() {
                                        var file = this;
                                        if (file.name == 'Foo') {
                                            alert(file.id);
                                        }
                                    });
                                },
                                function(responseFailed) {
                                    alert(responseFailed.error.message);
                                }
                          );
                        }
                    });
                },
                function(responseFailed) {
                    alert(responseFailed.error.message);
                }
            );  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you must check that you are receiving a folder or an album, and not a file, because I think that you cant browse for files in a file.

i.e

```
if (folder.type == 'folder' || folder.type == 'album')
    if (folder.name == 'FooBar') { //do the call }
```

before you calling the next api request.

Try if that helps

Comment: You were right. My skydrive contained more then just folders which in turn made the api to break. I mark your answer as accepted!

Comment: so folder, many amaze, very answer, such correct wow! @Verkion